# Is there any feature that is equivalent to Single in sandwich library?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I need to call sequential APIs. Is there any way to make it simple?

It's maybe related to 'map' feature or [this one](https://github.com/skydoves/sandwich/issues/11)

```
suspend fun reCheckout(
    orderData: OrderData
) = flow {
    loginAndRegister(orderData.phoneNumber).suspendOnSuccess {
        val jwt = "jwt ${data.auth.token}"
        Client.saveAuth(data)
        cancelOrder(
            orderData.orderId,
            OrderCancelRequestBody("store", "re-checkout")
        ).suspendOnSuccess {
            addMultiCartItem(jwt, orderData.cartItems).suspendOnSuccess {
                checkOut(orderData.checkoutBody!!).suspendOnSuccess {
                    emit(this.data)
                }.suspendOnError {
                    emit(this)
                }.suspendOnException {
                    emit(this)
                }
            }.suspendOnError {
                emit(this)
            }.suspendOnException {
                emit(this)
            }
        }.suspendOnError {
            emit(this)
        }.suspendOnException {
            emit(this)
        }
    }.suspendOnError {
        emit(this)
    }.suspendOnException {
        emit(this)
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's the right way or not. I'd like to have only one onError and onException here like Single in RxJava. Is that possible?

I also want to handle the data in ViewModel with onSuccess, onException, onError, etc. How can I implement it?

At this moment, since all the response are different, emits different types. So, I can get them as Any and then use `is` Keyword. In this way, viewModel will be messy. Is there any better way?

Comment: Do you ever emit more than once for these flows? If not, then you made it more complicated by using flows where you could use suspend functions which are naturally sequential.

Comment: Also, what is the type of these flows? Is this some custom success/error/exception wrapper? I'm sorry, I don't know sandwich if this is related to it.

Comment: @broot No, just once. I just want to make those APIs as one. If all is success, then, return the last API calls response, otherwise, return any errors or exceptions for the API that failed.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I would suggest to replace flows with suspend functions and provide a `flatMap()` function for your result class, so it could become something like: `doFirst().flatMap { doSecond(it) }.flatMap { doThird(it) }`. But that really depends of the details of your result class and the reason why you have chosen to use flows in the first place.

Comment: @broot, I am sorry, I am a beginner of coroutine, loginAndRegister, cancelOrder, addMultiCartItem, are already suspend function and I tried to change loginAndRegister.suspendOnSuccess to loginAndRegister.flatMap. But it doesn't have flatMap.

Comment: For anyone interested, same was asked here: https://github.com/skydoves/sandwich/issues/83 and there's a response from lib author.